# Post Api in Angularjs uncaught error

Tags: angularjs

I got error in Post Api in **Angularjs**

```
$scope.ok = function(){
    var data = {
        name: $scope.name
    }
    $http({
    method: 'POST', 
    url: '/api/myurl,
    params:data,
        }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.cancel();
       // $state.reload();
    }, function (response) {
        console.log('i am in error');
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); 
    });
}
```

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

Comment: change `url: '/api/myurl,` to `url: '/api/myurl',`

Comment: Tnaks it's my mistake